# How to pass data from one form to another?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wampserver

I am using C#, and wamp server. I want to pass the data that I input in the first form and display it in the second form. I want to know the syntax that I need to pass it. You can see in the picture. thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: I think you can pass the data with property or constructor.

Comment: (1) `I want to know the syntax that I need to pass it` is just a different way of asking us to write the code for you (2) Please post code, not images of code (3) The title and the posted code do not match in the slightest. Which forms? Why is there suddenly a database involved that you never mentioned? (4) Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: ... (5) "SELECT" is not a "NonQuery".

Comment: Sorry guys, I am a newbie in coding especially using the database, that why I am asking for help, please. I am searching for a tutorial that teaches the use of every syntax if you have any recommendation it will be a big help for me. thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want to know the sql query syntax or c#  syntax?

Comment: Yikes. This looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: Also, it's never a good idea to post an image of your code. It makes it much harder for people here to help you. There's an option built into the editor to get syntax highlighting automatically if you paste the text of the code directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code to pass data from one form to another form.

By the way, if you want to select data from database, you can use SqlDataAdapter to fill the dataset. Then you could set the dataset as the datasource.

Form1:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.tb.Text = textBox1.Text;
            form.ShowDialog();

        }
    }
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionstring = @"";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
            connection.Open();
            string sql = string.Format("select * from Teacher where Name='{0}'",textBox1.Text);
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            DataSet set = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(set);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = set.Tables[0];
        }

        public TextBox tb
        {
            get { return textBox1; }
            set { textBox1 = value; }

        }
    }
```

You can see the following picture to know what I am doing.

Result:

[image]